# what is the best way to long pause an exe

Tags: c++, sleep, thread-sleep, sleep-mode

I have made a program in c++  for changing the password of a system and I wanna run it for every 2 hours,then I end up with two choice in c++ ,one is `Sleep(ms)` and the other is using recent thread lib `this_thread::sleep_for(2h)[ 2h using std::chrono_literals]`.

The doubt I have been wandering is, does long pausing an `exe` will work the way we want, is it any other better way than what i mentioned?

I have also planned to put my `exe` as a windows service.

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you trying to solve? You appear to have your solution already?

Comment: I want to confirm whether my solution is what ultimately chosen by everyone as best.

Comment: @Richard_G your approach in general wouldn't be *ultimately chosen by everyone as best*.

Comment: Why not simply start it every two hours using operating system scheduler?

Comment: user2079303, i am looking for the some one who suggest me the best.

Comment: @Richard_G: What does "best" mean? According to what metrics? To suit what requirements? You are being extraordinarily vague.

Comment: lightness, I don't want anyone who come after me and look at my code then say he should have done something better than this!

Comment: Ari0nhh,No scheduled task, as I am changing the user password by overriding some of the user info I prefer service because it run as a system process and I hope it has high privilege than what it run as just task

Comment: @Richard_G So? Windows `at` scheduler runs as a `SYSTEM` account.  Unix `cron` tasks could be executed from `root` as well.

Answer (score 2):

> any other better way than what i mentioned?

Yes.

I suggest, that you do not pause the program at. Simply do the thing, and exit.

Extract the scheduling part to a separate program. You don't even need to write this scheduler, because it already exists on [most](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) [operating](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) [systems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: user2079303,No scheduled task, as I am changing the user password by overriding some of the user info I  prefer service because it run as a system process and I hope it has high privilege than what it  run as just task

Answer (score 2):

If you have some task that must be run periodically with long periods of waiting, you should use a program or script, that does the task and exits, and a scheduler, which handles the waiting. There're also questions you need to consider, for example:

- do you need to start your task if the scheduled time was missed (due to reboot, for example)
- do you allow several of your tasks to run at once, if time it takes to complete is longer than wait period

What you're trying to do is to implement a scheduler yourself. If this is what you want, then `sleep` is a posix function, and `chrono::thread::sleep_for` is cross-platform, so it's better to use the second one.

However, it's not generally recommended to implement schedulers, moreover, so simple ones.